# Como funciona um navegador mobile?

Tags: mobile, aplicação-web, navegador-de-internet

Nos navegadores mobiles geralmente temos o `Mode Fast`, aportuguesando vira '`Modo Rápido`', onde, ele deixa os sites mais leves para serem carregados, sei que parte disso é que o próprio site considera o acesso como acesso Mobile, mas outra parte é o próprio navegador que altera, pode-se notar diferenças no site do Facebook quando acessado pelo UCBrowser e pelo Opera Mini. Bom a dúvida que tenho é exatamente essa, como isso funciona, como um navegador pode alterar o código de uma página, e como fazer isso em código? Outra dúvida é quanto ao como os sites indicam que o acesso é mobile ou não, para ver se ele ativa ou não sua versão mobile, isso só pode ser feito com o CSS, com o `media`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como você disse, `CSS` e uma forma de se fazer layout responsivo.

Desde que seja programado para isso, o layout responsivo automaticamente se encaixa no dispositivo do usuário (mobile, desktop, etc...), ou seja, o site responsivo muda a sua aparência e disposição com base no tamanho da tela em que o site é exibido. Se o utilizador tem uma tela pequena, os elementos devem ser readaptados.

Mas não é o caso do Facebook, até porque o site não é responsivo (media queries são usadas em sites responsivos). O que o Facebook faz é utilizar javascript para verificar qual o dispositivo (mobile, desktop, etc...) e redirecionar para o endereço correto para o dispositivo, que no caso seria "http://m.facebook.com".

Para verificar qual o dispositivo que o utilizador está a usar, conheço essa lib que facilita muito: https://github.com/matthewhudson/device.js

Um exemplo de como verificar qual o dispositivo que o utilizador está a usar:

```
<script src="device.js"></script>
<script>
    var mobile  = device.mobile(),
        tablet  = device.tablet(),
        desktop = device.desktop();

    if(mobile) 
        alert("Acesso via mobile");
    else if(tablet) 
        alert("Acesso via tablet");
    else if(desktop) 
        alert("Acesso via desktop");
</script>
```

Há outras utilidades para essa lib, como por exemplo, saber se o utilizador está usando android ou ios, etc...

Vale a pena dar uma olhada na documentação.